# Why does a Gaussian beam shrink in diameter when approaching a focal point?

Tags: laser, gauss-law, laser-interaction, laser-cavity

[image]

I'm basing my question on the above graphic. I've been trying to research this, but I'm having trouble getting it into my head. The caption says it follows the $\frac{1}{e^2}$ point on beam intensity, which is, or looks to be around the Full Width Half Maximum of the Gaussian Beam's profile, but why *do* the dotted lines represent them? And why does the characteristics of a lens cause them to act in such a way?

Comment: Are you familiar with how the same [ray transfer (ABCD) matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_transfer_matrix_analysis) can be used to model both ray optics and Gaussian beam optics?

Comment: I see now @ThePhoton, appreciate that. Although, I'm afraid to say it's not making this seem rather intuitive to me. Is there a way it can be explained qualitatively?

Comment: You can go back to the lens physics and how the parts of the beam that go through less glass end up with retarded phase relative to the parts that go through more glass, and that leads to a converging beam for a convex lens. Or look at it in terms of the eikonal equation.